# mysql group by year diffrent from group by year and month

Tags: mysql

I am trying to make some reports regarding our orders and the products sold, revenue and the total weight, but when im grouping our orders together I get different results in some of my queries that should return the same.

The following is my queries:

### Monthly

```
SELECT
    MONTH(orders.date_purchased) as date,
    YEAR(orders.date_purchased) as year,
    count(DISTINCT orders.orders_id) AS total_orders,
    categories.fields_23 as currency
FROM
orders_shipping_products
Inner Join orders ON orders.orders_id = orders_shipping_products.orders_id
Inner Join categories ON categories.fields_6 = orders.shopping_store_category_id
WHERE
orders.orders_status NOT IN (0, 1, 99)
GROUP BY
date,
year,
categories.fields_23
ORDER by
    YEAR(orders.date_purchased),
    MONTH(orders.date_purchased) ASC,
    categories.fields_23
```

This returns for 2012 the following table, a total of 353:

```
+------+------+--------------+----------+
| date | year | total_orders | currency |
+------+------+--------------+----------+
|   11 | 2012 |           86 | EUR      |
|   12 | 2012 |          267 | EUR      |
+------+------+--------------+----------+
```

### Yearly

```
SELECT
    YEAR(orders.date_purchased) as year,
    count(DISTINCT orders.orders_id) AS total_orders,
    categories.fields_23 as currency
FROM
orders_shipping_products
Inner Join orders ON orders.orders_id = orders_shipping_products.orders_id
Inner Join categories ON categories.fields_6 = orders.shopping_store_category_id
WHERE
orders.orders_status NOT IN (0, 1, 99)
GROUP BY
year,
categories.fields_23
ORDER by
    YEAR(orders.date_purchased),
    categories.fields_23
```

it returns for 2012 the following

```
+------+--------------+----------+
| year | total_orders | currency |
+------+--------------+----------+
| 2012 |          351 | EUR      |
+------+--------------+----------+
```

The only thing that changes is the total_orders, total amount of products, the revenue and weight is the same. I just get two more orders when checking per month. I also checked with a selection and grouping by QUARTER, YEAR that returns the following:

```
+---------+------+--------------+----------+
| quarter | year | total_orders | currency |
+---------+------+--------------+----------+
|       4 | 2012 |          351 | EUR      |
+---------+------+--------------+----------+
```

This make me thinks, that i might be doing something wrong with my selections when i want to generate a report per month

### WITH ROLLUP

Daniel asked me to try add WITH ROLLUP on my query, follow is what i did and got in return

```
SELECT
    MONTH(orders.date_purchased) as date,
    YEAR(orders.date_purchased) as year,
    count(DISTINCT orders.orders_id) AS total_orders,
    categories.fields_23 as currency
FROM
orders_shipping_products
Inner Join orders ON orders.orders_id = orders_shipping_products.orders_id
Inner Join categories ON categories.fields_6 = orders.shopping_store_category_id
WHERE
orders.orders_status NOT IN (0, 1, 99)
GROUP BY
year,
date,
categories.fields_23 WITH ROLLUP
```

This is the returned data:

```
+------+------+--------------+----------+
| date | year | total_orders | currency |
+------+------+--------------+----------+
| 11   | 2012 |           86 | EUR      |
| 11   | 2012 |           86 | NULL     |
| 12   | 2012 |          267 | EUR      |
| 12   | 2012 |          267 | NULL     |
| NULL | 2012 |          351 | NULL     |
+------+------+--------------+----------+
```

Comment: Does the `orders` table have unique `orders_id` or can it be that one order has a Novermber row and a December row too? -- Also, you meant 353 instead of 253.

Comment: Orders_id is unique, and if that was the case, the other values like total amount of products, should also be affected ?

Comment: True, so indeed a mystery. A simple and stupid thing you could do is to find order_id's that are in the first result but not in the second and sniff around there.

Comment: On the monthly report, try using `group by date_format( orders.date_purchased, '%Y%m' )`.

Comment: Can you please run your first query with `WITH ROLLUP`, inverting the year, date order, and dropping the `ORDER BY` clause, as follows: `...GROUP BY year, date, categories.fields_23 WITH ROLLUP;` What do you see for `date=NULL` (i.e. all months)? (see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html) (Maybe you should rename `date` to `month` for clarity.)

Comment: Hi @DanielSparing I will update my question with the information

Comment: @Ravinder sadly this dont change anything. it returns the same data as MONTH() YEAR()

Comment: I rechecked orders_id and it where not unique, in fact there where 2-3 the same orders id and some of them where located in different months. I found that there where another column in my table i could use to make the system return what seems like more correct data, since both "Monthly", "yearly" and "quarterly" reports now all is equal (at least for 2012).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rechecked orders_id and it where not unique, in fact there where 2-3 the same orders id and some of them where located in different months. Found that a combination of orders_id and another column made it up for the real unique id. adding this to my join, solved everything.